# UpdateSourceTrigger not working?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to validate the text in a textbox when a key is pressed. Here's the shortest code sample that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135"
                 Text="{Binding ValidationRules.EmailAddress, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

"ValidationRules" class:

```
 class ValidationRules
    {
        string email = "";
        public string EmailAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return email;
            }

            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting!");
                //Only check if there is any text for now...
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                email = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

When I start typing in the textbox, I don't get "Setting" as console output, even though I'm using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. I've done my research but all the examples I could find are long winding and confusing. I would also appreciate it if you could point out any other mistakes I have in validation, but try to explain in simple terms if possible because I'm new to WPF.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Immediate window?

Comment: Where have you set the `DataContext` to the `ValidationRules` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be an issue on where you are setting your DataContext.

This example seems to work fine:

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ValidationRules = new ValidationRules();
    }

    private ValidationRules _validation;
    public ValidationRules ValidationRules
    {
        get { return _validation; }
        set { _validation = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ValidationRules"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
 }

public class ValidationRules : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string email = "";
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return email;
        }

        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting!");
            //Only check if there is any text for now...
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            email = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EmailAddress");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

}
```

Xaml

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="125.078" Width="236.441" x:Name="UI" >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135"
                 Text="{Binding ValidationRules.EmailAddress, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use "throw new Exception()" however, it pauses execution ("Exception was unhandled by user code"). Is there some error you can throw that doesn't do that but still has the desired effect, or is there another way to do it?